# How to bind a checkbox to DB in ASP.Net webforms?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I want to bind a Checkbox to the database.

My Code:

```
cblstudent.DataSource = 
    (from s in dbcore.person select new {s.Id,s.FullName} ).ToList()
cblstudent.DataValueField = "Id";
cblstudent.DataTextField = "FullName";
cblstudent.DataBind();
```

Please help me debug this code. The error I get is "Error Databind"

The target table name in database is "**person**".

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate a little more on what your problem is. By focusing on the error you get you will have more chances of finding someone to answer your question. The error `Error Databind` is too general in this context.

Comment: I think the problem is the linq I use in datasource.
I wanted the databaind check box list command as code first